# Click outside button to close popup using toggle

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

I used toggle to make a search form from a button. But I want click outside any position to close search form, not only using button.

HTML

```
<a href="#" data-mini="false" data-theme="e" data-role="button" class="opensearch" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="right">Search</a>
<div class="search_field" style="display:none;">
    <form>
        <input name="search" class="search" value="" placeholder="Search Item...." type="text" data-theme="e" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" data-mini="false" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Jquery :

```
 $(function() {
     $(".opensearch").on('click', tapHandler);
     function tapHandler(event) {
         $('.search_field').toggle();
         $('.search').focus();
     }
 });
```

Demo of [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aH4QM/14/)

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Please read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element

Answer (score 4):

Use the blur event:

```
$(".search").on("blur",function(){
    $('.search_field').toggle();
});
```

Updated fiddle: [**JsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aH4QM/30/)

---

[Edit] You might want to check if the new focus is not on the search icon before hiding the field:

```
$(".search").on("blur",function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    var target = document.activeElement;
    target = target ? target.id||target.tagName||target : '';

    if(target!="INPUT"){
        $('.search_field').toggle();
    }

  }, 1);        
});
```

Better with the id of the button though....

Example: [**JsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aH4QM/32/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```js
 $(function() {

   $(".opensearch").on('click', tapHandler);
   //add a click handler to the document object
   $(document).on('click', function(e) {
     //if the click is happening inside the search_field or opensearch elements then don't do anything
     if ($(e.target).closest('.search_field, .opensearch').length == 0) {
       $('.search_field').hide();
     }
   });

   function tapHandler(event) {
     $('.search_field').toggle();
     $('.search').focus();
   }

 });
```

```css
.search_field {
  padding: 10px 10px 0;
  position: relative;
}
.search_field .ui-submit {
  bottom: -2px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-mini="false" data-theme="e" data-role="button" class="opensearch" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="right">Search</a>

<div class="search_field" style="display:none;">
  <form>
    <input name="search" class="search" value="" placeholder="Search Item...." type="text" data-theme="e" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" data-mini="false" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" />
  </form>
</div>
```